# Prägnante und kurze deutsche Entsprechung zu "virtue signalling"?

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

Mir ist jetzt schon ein paar mal aufgefallen, daß wir im Deutschen keine Entsprechung des englischen Begriffs "virtue signalling" (bedeutet etwa: die Zurschaustellung der eigenen Tugendhaftigkeit) zu haben scheinen oder mir dieser zumindest in dem Moment wo ich den Begriff gern benutzen würde nicht greifbar ist.

Klar kann ich die sperrige Bedeutungsumschreibung von oben verwenden, aber die ist eben ... sperrig. Und im Deutschen würde ich erwarten, daß wir *ein* zusammengesetztes Substantiv für den englischen Begriff haben, welches den Sinn exakt wiedergibt.

Ich könnte mich jetzt an seltsam klingenden Übersetzungen versuchen wie: Tugendzurschaustellung oder Tugendsignalisierung (klingt für mich eher schräg).

Haben wir im Deutschen eine Entsprechung zu "virtue signalling" die kurz und prägnant daherkommt?

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage Das trifft es alles nicht. Ein _Moralapostel_ ist jemand, der Moral nur predigt, sie aber nicht lebt; das ist etwas völlig anderes. Die anderen beiden Begriffe sind zu unspezifisch.

Comment: Ein Lehnwort, das im Deutschen verwendet wird, _ist_ ein deutsches Wort. :)

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach daß es sich bei "virtue signalling" um ein Lehnwort handelt, müßtest Du aber erst einmal belegen. Allein die Nutzung von Fremdwörtern in einem deutschen Satz macht sie noch nicht zu Lehnworten. Es gibt eine Menge Lehnworte, aber soweit ich mich entsinne, gehorchen diese den grundlegenden Regeln der deutschen Grammatik. Das kann ich (noch!) nicht bei "virtue signalling" erkennen. Übrigens frage ich mich gerade ob bspw. lateinische Namen von Krankheiten oder Knochen (also Fachbegriffe) _wirkliche_ Lehnworte im Deutschen sind. Werde das einmal recherchieren.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gesucht wird ein Begriff, der dem Englischen *virtue signalling* entspricht und somit für ***Zurschaustellung der eigenen Tugendhaftigkeit*** stehen kann, aber kürzer und prägnanter ist.

Recht nahe kommt dem wohl die

> Frömmelei

wenn auch das Wort (und das Verhalten) etwas aus der Mode gekommen sind. Verwandt ist auch die

> Prüderie

bei der es ebenfalls vor allem um den Anschein geht, denn wie sehr im stillen Kämmerlein (wenn die Öffentlichkeit nicht mehr zuschaut) von der naserümpfenden Abwendung vom Sexuellen noch etwas übrig bleibt, weiß man nicht.

Drittens könnte man noch die

> Regelfuchserei

und die

> Paragraphenreiterei

anführen, bei der es um das strikte Einhalten von Normen geht. Allerdings ist hier wohl der Aspekt der Zurschaustellung weniger ausgeprägt, eher geht es um Machtfragen und Rechthabenwollen.

Lässt man als Lösung auch Neologismen zu (einige haben sich darin schon versucht), so schlage ich

> Tugendprotzerei

vor, das mir als Wort stilistisch homogener scheint als von anderen bisher erwähnte Varianten wie *Tugendangeberei* oder *Tugendsignalisierung*. Daneben könnte eine betroffene Person auch einen

> Tugendfimmel

haben, was als Wort sehr schön ist, aber einer anderen syntaktischen Einbindung bedarf als die vorgenannten Substantive.

Leichter wird es, wenn neben Substantiven auch Adjektive oder ganze Wendungen als Antwort gelten:

> demonstrativ tugendhaft
>
> übertugendhaft
>
> seine Tugend vor sich hertragen
>
> seine Tugend als Monstranz vor sich hertragen

---

Anmerkung zum

> Gutmenschentum

das in anderen Antworten angedeutet (aber noch nicht verbatim vorgeschlagen) wurde. Bei diesem Vorschlag stört mich, dass es - in meinem Verständnis - eine andere Verwendung hat. Wo immer ich im Alltag Leute den Vorwurf des *Gutmenschentums* äußern höre, ist dieser gemünzt auf Dritte, denen es nicht um die *Zurschaustellung* ethisch begründeten Verhaltens geht sondern um das ethisch begründete Verhalten *an sich*, welches aber nach Meinung derer, die den Vorwurf des Gutmenschentums äußern, ein Lächerliches sei.

Oder in anderen Worten: Ich kann einem anderen die *Zurschaustellung von Tugendhaftigkeit* bescheinigen, ohne die Tugendhaftigkeit als solche lächerlich zu finden. Werfe ich ihm *Gutmenschentum* vor, sage ich aber, dass ich schon seine Tugendhaftigkeit an sich lächerlich finde, nicht nur die Zurschaustellung.

Comment: Tugendprotzerei finde ich in der Tat auch noch einmal einen Tick passender als Gutmenschelei. Mal sehen wie sich die Worte im Sprachgebrauch so machen. Danke.

Comment: Beste Antwort bisher, vor Allem auch wegen der Diskussion der verschiedenen Varianten. Auch schön, dass du _Frömmelei_ ausgegraben hast, das ist es in der Tat. +1

Comment: Die letzten Absätze beschreiben, wie Teile des rechten Spektrums "Gutmenschentum" seit 2015 verwenden, aber mit der eigentlichen Definition (z.B. https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gutmensch) hat das nur sehr wenig zu tun. Die ist deutlich näher an "virtue signalling".

Answer (score 4):

Der Begriff stammt aus der englisch geprägten (evolutions-)psychologischen Fachliteratur. Viele Begriffe der Fachliteratur werden als Lehnworte verwendet, so auch dieses: Man verwendet im Deutschen das englische Fremdwort *Virtue Signaling*. Auch der alleinstehende Begriff *Signaling* ist sowohl [in der Ökonomie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signaling_(Wirtschaftswissenschaften)) als auch [in der Verhaltensbiologie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signaling_(Verhaltensbiologie)) etabliert.

Viele deutsche Begriffe, die moralisches oder vermeintlich moralisches Handeln kritisieren (etwa: *moralinsauer*, *Gutmensch*, *Moralapostel*), treffen die Bedeutung von *virtue signalling* nicht richtig, weil beim Begriff *virtue signalling* zunächst einmal nicht eine Kritik, sondern eine Erklärung von Verhalten im Vordergrund steht. Sicher kann daraus eine Kritik im Sinne verborgenerer, "eigentlicher" Motive abgeleitet werden und sicher geschieht das auch oft, wenn der Begriff *virtue signalling* im Englischen verwendet wird, dennoch hat *virtue signalling* eine deskriptive Dimension die bei den deutschen Begriffen aus diesem semantischen Feld fehlt.

Comment: Als Lehnwort ist es aber nach deutscher Rechtschreibung zu schreiben, also Virtuesignalling. Auch beschreibt der Begriff m. E. ein Verhalten, er erklärt es nicht.

Comment: Ja, mit der Schreibung hast du Recht, das habe ich angepasst. Danke! Zu Erklärung / Beschreibung: Doch, der Begriff beinhaltet im Rahmen der Evolutionsbiologie genau eine Erklärung für augenscheinlich altruistisches Verhalten. Die Frage, die in diesem Paradigma gestellt wird, ist: Warum "lohnt" es sich, sich selbst durch altruistische Handlungen zu schaden? Und die Antwort ist: Es lohnt sich, weil es ein soziales Signal ist, das Vertrauen bildet, sodass die Handlung am Ende doch in Fitness-Vorteilen resultiert. Das ist genau das, was der Begriff Virtue Signaling bezeichnet.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach etwas OT aber wieso genau sollte Altruismus dem Individuum _schaden_ welches sich so verhält? Zumal immer auch die Frage ist ob es nicht doch _irgendwelche_ Motive gibt. Um bei SO zu bleiben. Ich habe _mehrfach_ nach Jahren meine eigenen Antworten wiederentdeckt und so effektiv mir selber geholfen. Das ist wie bei Dokumentation von Quelltext. Man _kann_ es so sehen, daß es für die Kollegen ist. Ich sehe das für die Kollegen eher als Kollateralnutzen und schreibe die Dokumentation meist für mein zukünftiges ich.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Das ist einfache eine Frage der Definition des Begriffs _Altruismus_. Eine übliche Definition sagt, dass eine altruistische Handlung eine Handlung ist, die dem Handelnden schadet (indem sie mehr Kosten als Nutzen aufweist, etwa), dem Empfangenden aber nützt. Aber man kann es natürlich auch anders definieren, etwa so, dass die Handlung für den Handelnden nutzenneutral ist. Dass es dabei doch verborgene Motive gibt, ist ja genau der Erklärungsansatz, des Begriffs _Virtue Signaling_. Es gibt auch Leute, die sagen, dass es A. in dieser Form nicht gibt; aber das führt hier zu weit

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach alles klar, diese Definition war mir noch nicht geläufig (also explizit mit dem Schaden für das altruistische Individuum).

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Deine Erklärung für Virtuesignalling kenne ich, aber sie steckt nicht im Begriff. Das Wort beschreibt ein Verhalten und unterstellt dem Handelnden die Absicht, dass sein Handeln wahrgenommen wird. Wenn die Erklärung dem Leser/Hörer nicht bekannt ist, dann muss sie separat gegeben werden.

Answer (score 4):

Ich werfe hier einmal das

> Pharisäertum

siehe z. B. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pharisaeertum) in den Ring. Das ist mir im Unterschied zu einigen anderen der genannten Alternativen schon in freier Wildbahn begegnet.

Answer (score 2):

Da *virtue signalling* im Englischen außerhalb von Fachaufsätzen dazu verwendet wird, dem Gegenüber Heuchelei vorzuwerfen, biete ich die Neuerfindung

> Gutmenschelei

Das würde ich z.B. dem Donald Trump auf die Zunge legen, sollte mich jemand ohne Englischkenntnisse fragen, was der da eigentlich gerade gesagt hat.

Comment: *Das Wörterbuch des Gutmenschen. Zur Kritik der moralisch korrekten Schaumsprache.* Mhmm-hmmm.

Comment: Ich würde stark davon abraten, das Wort „Gutmensch“ oder Abwandlungen davon zu verwenden.

Comment: Warum? Ok, *Schaumschläger* ist auch toll.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSp8IyaKCs0

Comment: @Janka: Man stellt sich mit der Wortwahl immer in einen Kontext. Ich sehe es als Aufgabe dieses Forums, über sprachliche Gegebenheiten Auskunft zu geben und damit Reflexion über Sprache zu ermöglichen. Und der Kontext des Worts _Gutmensch_ ist eine sprachliche Gegebenheit. Wenn ein Begriff, wie _Gutmensch_ vor Allem von Rechtspopulisten und -extremisten als Kampfbegriff verwendet wird, dann sollte das imho nicht mit "these are only words" beiseite gewischt werden. Man kann das natürlich verwenden, aber wir sollten auf diese Konnotation hinweisen. Sonst leisten wir einen Bärendienst.

Comment: Wenn ich für jemanden nicht des Englischen mächtigen den Donald Trump wiedergeben muss, lege ich dem das Wort *Gutmensch* auf die Zunge. Weil er es sagen würde, wenn er deutsch könnte.

Comment: (George Carlin habe ich nicht ohne Grund verlinkt. Weichgespülte Sprache ist ein Kennzeichen von Schurkerei. Wo der *Gutmensch* da einzusortieren ist ergibt sich nicht aus dem Begriff, und auch nicht daraus, wer ihn gebraucht, sondern zu welchem Zweck.)

Comment: Das Argument mit der Übersetzung Donald Trumps trifft ins Schwarze. Ich habe gar nichts dagegen, _Gutmenschelei_ als eine mögliche Übertragung von _virtue signalling_ anzusehen. Ich denke aber, ein Kommentar über den besagten Kontext wäre angebracht. Wenn sich das Ergebnis der in den Kommentaren geführten Diskussion in der Antwort widerspiegelte, wäre es eine noch bessere Antwort, denke ich.

Comment: Deshalb schrieb ich ja *Wie virtue signalling im Englischen hat es die Konnotation der Heuchelei, sollte es nicht gerade in einem Fachaufsatz verwendet werden.*

Comment: Ich habe es jetzt mal einfacher verständlich formuliert.

Comment: Ich empfinde "Gutmensch" als Kampfbegriff der Rechten und "virtue signalling" nicht.

Comment: Dann ist dir einiges entgangen.

Answer (score 2):

*Tugendapostel* oder *Moralapostel* könnte, je nach Kontext, passen.

Comment: Unter _Moralapostel_ versteht man eigentlich jemanden, der Moral nur lehrt, sich aber nicht an seine eigene Lehre hält. Das ist nochmal ein bisschen was anderes. Zunächstmal bezeichnet _Virtue Signaling_ eine Handlung, _Moralapostel_ eine Person. Aber wichtiger: Derjenige, der Virtue Signalling betreibt, hält sich ja an seine Moral. Die Unterstellung ist nur, dass er das aus anderen, letztlich eigennützigen Motiven tut. Das kann also zwar auch eine Kritik an Moral sein, aber es ist eine andere Kritik als _Moralapostel_.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach daß sich der Handelnde bei "virtue signalling" an seine Moral hält ist eine Tautologie. Denn Moral ist _immer_ subjektiv und damit ist es logisch, daß derjenige entsprechend seiner eigenen Moral handelt. Allerdings ist die Frage inwieweit sich derjenige evtl. selbst belügt davon weitgehend unberührt. Ich frage mich bspw. bei "geistlichen Würdenträgern" immer wieder inwieweit die an das glauben was sie anderen predigen. Aber die sprichwörtliche Monstranz welche so ein "Würdenträger" vor sich her trägt entspricht zumeist sehr wohl "virtue signalling" ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L Nein, das ist nicht tautologisch. Denn der Moralapostel predigt eine Moral, an die er sich dann nicht hält ("Wasser predigen und Wein trinken"). Derjenige, der Virtue Signaling betreibt, verhält sich ja entsprechend der "Tugend", die er signalisiert. Moral nur zu predigen ist gerade __kein__ Virtue Signaling. Das Wesentliche an dem Signal sind die Kosten, die das Signal für den Signalgebenden hat. Aber das ist alles Diskussion, die hier eigentlich nicht hingehört.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach ich weiß, daß Du das bereits mehrfach behauptet hast; sehe ich allerdings nicht ganz so.

Comment: Ja, das ist halt die Definition von Virtue Signaling :) Siehe Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtue_signalling "It is concerned with honest signals." Ohne ehrliche, das heißt kostspielige Signale ergibt der ganze Begriff gar keinen Sinn.

Comment: Genau das ist aber der Vorwurf, wenn der Begriff *virtue signalling* nicht-fachsprachlich verwendet wird. Sonst ergäbe es ja überhaupt keinen Sinn, das jemandem an den Kopf zu werfen.

Comment: @Janka Ja, du hast Recht. Ich war zu sehr auf die fachsprachliche Bedeutung fokussiert. Aber es gibt auch schon im Englischen eine erweiterte Bedeutung, die in das semantische Feld um _Bigotterie_, _Moralapostel_ usw. passt. Und diese erweiterte Bedeutung kann und sollte sich dann auch in der gesuchten deutschen Entsprechung wiederfinden. Das habe ich zu eng gesehen. Danke für die Geduld.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ich weiß eigentlich nicht, wie du darauf kommst, ein Moral- oder Tugendapostel würde sich prinzipiell nicht an seine eigenen Regeln halten. Für mich impliziert der Begriff das nicht.

Answer (score -1):

Man muss hier wissenschaftlichen und umgangssprachlichen Gebrauch unterscheiden. In jedem Fall wäre die Verwendung des Anglizismus selbst eine Art Virtue Signalling. Es ist zwar denkbar das Konzept sei älter als die Fachliteratur, die den Begriff prägte, und daher leicht zu umschreiben. Das würde das Signal, bzw. dessen Kraft schwächen. *Signalverstärkung* oder *Rückkopplung* wäre soweit allenfalls in technischer Sprache gebräuchlich.

Interessant ist der umgangssprachliche Gebrauch dagegen eher nicht, da zumeist abwertend oder unpräzise. Es gibt sicherlich verschiedene kontextabhängige Begriffe. Gesucht wird dennoch nach einem Substitut für

> "[Virtue signalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtue_Signalling)** is the conspicuous expression of moral values."
>
> - ... ist der merkwürdige Ausdruck moralischer Werte. *[Übersetzung meine]

---

Bspw. *Deutschtümelei* wäre vom Kontext abhängig. Klar kann man dagegen halten, das, was als *Deutschtümelei* bezeichnet wird, hätte auch Substanz hinter der Fassade. Das kann man bei *Virtue Signaling* aber auch, soweit es nicht eigentlich *Lippenbekenntnis* bedeutet. *Gleichschaltung*, *Anbiedern*, o.ä. wären noch stärker negativ. Oft ist eigentlich *Nebelkerze* gemeint, also das Verschleiern wahrer Absichten, Vgl *sich mit fremden Federn schmücken*. Anders wird ins Lächerliche ziehend auch vom *Schwanzlängenvergleich* bzw. hochtrabend von *Kräftemessen* gesprochen.

*Zurschaustellen* ist das eigentliche *Signalling*. Von *Virtue* oder sonstiger Wertung ist dabei kaum die Rede. *Sich in den Vordergrund rücken* ist ebenso subtil negativ besetzt. *Herausstellen, hervorstellen, hervorheben, exponieren, präsentieren* oder einfach *signalisieren* sind dagegen recht neutral. In alledem wird der erfragte Kontext nicht mehr erkennbar, wenngleich die ursprünglich nicht wertenden Bedeutung nahe liegt, die im Übertragenen Sinne eine *Einladung* bezeichnet; vgl. *einladendes Aussehen*. Etwas weiter hergeholt wäre *Reiz, reizen* passend, soweit *reizend* eine gewisse mehrdeutigkeit bewahrt, und *Reiz, aufreizen* hinreichend psychologische Bedeutung ähnlich *Signal* tragen. Vgl auch *reizen* im Skat neben En *raise* im Poker. *Gebaren* (vs *Gebühr, ungebührend, Bürde* etc., s. *Geschäfts-Gebaren*) steht dem nicht fern.

Um auf Moralinsäure zurückzukommen, würde ich schlussendlich plädieren für:

> Angeben

Salop gesagt wird auch von *angebenden Angebern* gesprochen. *gift* "Gabe" ist dabei etwa parallel zu *Tugendhaftigkeig*, jedoch im Sinne *Talent* davon zu unterscheiden: *virtuos* ist noch stärker als *begabt*. Mit *begnadeten Künstlern*, *Gnädigkeit* oder *Bescheidenheit* hat das aber wenig zu tun, daher sagt man Angebern gern *falsche Bescheidenheit* nach.

Sofern Angeben in gewissen Gesellschaftsschichten zum MO gehört, wird dagegen von *Machtdemonstration* oder *Statussymbolik* gesprochen, welche oft auch der *Abschreckung* dienen.

*Angabe* "Eröffnung" (vgl. *jemandem etwas eröffnen* "verraten") passt sodann auch zur oben bezeichneten *Einladung*. Vgl. dagegen *verladen* "in die Irre führen", *ausladend*, *sich entladen, sich entledigen* und *eine große Klappe*.

Im Sinne *tonangebend* ist zwar eine positive Konnotation erkennbar, und der *Angeber* ohne *Ton* quasi nur eine zutiefst sarkastische Variante davon.

Wegen dem Fokus auf Rollenverteilung im soziale Gefüge ist dieses Wort letztendlich auch unpassend. Zudem wird *abgeben* und *Altruismus* quasi ausgeschlossen und Gier, Geiz oder Geilheit impliziert.

---

Positiver besetzt ist dagegen *Tugend*, welches dennoch kontextuell und daher subjektiv ist und alleinstehend nur *virtue* übersetzt, und das nicht besonders treffend, sehr eng auf christlichen Kontext gemünzt.

Insofern Tugend als Sammelbegriff auch Zurückhaltung bezeichnet, ist es mit *virtue signalling* eigentlich nicht vereinbar, lediglich im Sinne den Aussenstehenden nicht erkennbarer Zeichen, die erst durch den Vorwurf des Tugendzurschaustellens allgemein kenntlich gemacht werden würden. Siehe dahingehend auch *tunlichst*, sofern vergleichbar mit *Tugend* (nur in *tunlichst unterlassen*).

Auf die Herkunft des Wortes einzugehen, das bspw. bei [Pfeiffer](https://dwds.org/wb/taugen) oder Kluge/Seeboldt auf eine Bedeutung *viel Milch geben* zurückgeführt wird, erspare ich mir. Nur so viel. Sanskrit, insb das Rig-Vedische, ist zwar vergleichsweise alt, aber nur bedingt konservativ; Die Bedeutung bzgl. *Milch*, die soweit einzig in Sanskrit belegt zu sein scheint, könnte ebenso gut umgekehrt von einem allgemein abstrakten Begriff spezialisiert worden, oder gar zufällig lautlich ähnlich sein. Daher folgt nur ein aus Rückschlüssen gewonnener Vorschlag.

> Werbung ist der augenscheinliche Ausdruck moralischer Werte

Ggf. fehlt dabei ein Attributiver Vorsatz. *ermutigend*, *Anhänger*, ... Tatsächlich findet g-books immerhin drei Ergebnisse jüngerer Zeit für "Tugendwerbung", von denen zwei gleichzeitig von Moral reden, natürlich im Religiösen Kontext. Das dritte könnte ein OCR Fehler für "Jugendwerbung sein"; So oder so, vgl "Jünger".

Answer (score -1):

Tümelei ist doch spitze!
Geht je nach Kenntnisstand des Kundtuers auch in Richtung Schaumschlägerei wie ich finde und ist etwas anderes als eine *red flag*.